# What word descriptions are there?

Tags: expressions, idioms, synonyms

I know the title is a bit confusing, English is not my first language.
Basically, I'll explain what I mean with a few examples below:

> Gramograms - words that sound like letters.(i.e 'are' and 'R', 'cue' and 'q', 'bee' and b. You get the point)
>
> Homonyms - words that sound alike but have different meanings('accept' and 'except', 'die' and 'dye', etc)
>
> Palindromes - words that are spelled the same backwards. ('racecar', 'radar', 'level', are all spelled backwards the same)
>
> Misnomers - a word or term that suggests a meaning that is known to be wrong('Funny bone' isn't a bone but a nerve, 'French Horns' are actually German, 'Koala bears' aren't beards, etc)
>
> Autonyms - word that expresses a property that it also possesses("word" is a word, "English" is in English, "pentasyllabic" has 5 syllabels, etc)

I have two question:

1. Is there a full list of these? What others do you know of?
2. Is there a word for words that describe words?

Comment: I've never seen anything that seems like a reasonably comprehensive list.

Comment: If no one seems to have a list, perhaps we should attempt to make one? I really want a list like that.

Comment: Although lists are a common "question" type in other SE domains, I'm not sure that they are allowed in EL&U.

Comment: Would your list include all metalinguistic categories, for example words for grammatical categories (e.g. "articles" and "prepositions") and words like "monosyllabic" and "polysyllabic"? Or just the exotic varieties that have -nym, -nom, -gram, etc. affixation?

Comment: Hmm, I think just the exotic varieties, though monosyllabic would also be included.

Either way, any one know other examples of these? Or what these are called?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request for resources.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a single, comprehensive list but the [Linguistic morphology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Linguistic_morphology) page on Wikipedia seems like a good starting point.

It includes a link to the [Types of words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Types_of_words) page, which includes many *-nyms*.